# How to reverse byte order in uint256 or bytes32?

Tags: solidity, evm

Need to convert BigEndian to LittleEndian or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [very efficient algorithm](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel) for reversing fixed-2^n-length integers.

This optimization improved gas usage by almost 2x in one of the cases here: https://github.com/summa-tx/bitcoin-spv/pull/107#issuecomment-578010422

```
function reverse(uint256 input) internal pure returns (uint256 v) {
    v = input;

    // swap bytes
    v = ((v & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8) |
        ((v & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8);

    // swap 2-byte long pairs
    v = ((v & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16) |
        ((v & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16);

    // swap 4-byte long pairs
    v = ((v & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32) |
        ((v & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32);

    // swap 8-byte long pairs
    v = ((v & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000) >> 64) |
        ((v & 0x0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) << 64);

    // swap 16-byte long pairs
    v = (v >> 128) | (v << 128);
}
```

Version for `uint128`:

```
function reverse(uint128 input) internal pure returns (uint128 v) {
    v = input;

    // swap bytes
    v = ((v & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8) |
        ((v & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8);

    // swap 2-byte long pairs
    v = ((v & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16) |
        ((v & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16);

    // swap 4-byte long pairs
    v = ((v & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32) |
        ((v & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32);

    // swap 8-byte long pairs
    v = (v >> 64) | (v << 64);
}
```

Version for `uint64`:

```
function reverse(uint64 input) internal pure returns (uint64 v) {
    v = input;

    // swap bytes
    v = ((v & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8) |
        ((v & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8);

    // swap 2-byte long pairs
    v = ((v & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16) |
        ((v & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16);

    // swap 4-byte long pairs
    v = (v >> 32) | (v << 32);
}
```

Version for `uint32`:

```
function reverse(uint32 input) internal pure returns (uint32 v) {
    v = input;

    // swap bytes
    v = ((v & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8) |
        ((v & 0x00FF00FF) << 8);

    // swap 2-byte long pairs
    v = (v >> 16) | (v << 16);
}
```

Version for `uint16`:

```
function reverse(uint16 input) internal pure returns (uint16 v) {
    v = input;

    // swap bytes
    v = (v >> 8) | (v << 8);
}
```

Comment: Neither `input` nor `r` are being used here. This function will always return 0.

Comment: BTW, this is not "for reversing fixed-2^n-length integers", it's for reversing 256-length integers.

Comment: Fixed `r` to `v`. This code could be easily reduced to work with `uint128` or `uint64`.