# How to reverse a Solidity bytes sorting?

Tags: solidity, bytes, bytes32

Suppose I have this bytes pad:

`0x0123456789abcdef`

How can I make it like this:

`0xfedcba9876543210`

Just by Solidity and not by Assembly.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83626/how-to-reverse-byte-order-in-uint256-or-bytes32

Comment: @ikijong I checked that. That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: have you tried using that for `uint64`?

Comment: @ikijong No, What should I do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83626/how-to-reverse-byte-order-in-uint256-or-bytes32) you can reverse a `bytes8` like this:

```
function reverse(bytes8 input) external pure returns (bytes8 v) {
    v = input;

    // swap nibble (half of an 8-bit byte)
    v = ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) << 4) | 
        ((v & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0) >> 4);

    // swap 1-byte
    v = ((v & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8) |
        ((v & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8);

    // swap 2-byte long pairs
    v = ((v & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16) |
        ((v & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16);

    // swap 4-byte long pairs
    v = (v >> 32) | (v << 32);
}
```

Compared to the related example where a `uint` was reversed, I had to swap the nibble because `byte` is padded to the lower-order (right) while `uint` are padded to the left (see: [bytes](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity-examples/blob/master/docs/bytes/Bytes.md#bytes)).